# I am using jmeter and performed load test with 100 users

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter and performed load test with 100 users and got http response 200 but cant find the user hit on my server in "No of user tracker" section. its was just showing the 6 real users which was actually right.

Why i am not able to see those 100 request which i generated by jmeter

Comment: Are you sure that the script works fine?

Comment: Any feedback on answers, if OK it should be accepted and upvoted

Comment: Ya script is running totally fine and getting 200 status code but unable to track on Google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

If your tracking is based on Javascript execution, remember that JMeter is not a browser so it does not execute the Javascript contained in a response (HTML Page).

Comment: so what can be the solution to my problem ?

Comment: @sourabh shukla you can always mimic the XHR call made by the tracking script as a separate sampler.